# PHP create MySql command to use multi where clause from some conditions

Tags: php

I have some conditions such as :

```
productId = 1 and marketId = 1
productId = 2 and marketId = 2
productId = 3 and marketId = 3
productId = 4 and marketId = 4
productId = 5 and marketId = 5
```

and I want to fetch that which they are in array to create single mysql command, count of this conditions are custom, I want to get result with one sql command like with:

```
SELECT * FROM images 
    WHERE productId = 1 AND marketId = 1 
    OR    productId = 2 and marketId = 2
    OR    productId = 3 and marketId = 3
```

how can I do that? My code is not correct and that sum all values:

```
 <?php
    $arr = [
        [
            'productId' => '1',
            'marketId' => '1',
        ],
        [
            'productId' => '2',
            'marketId' => '2',
        ],
        [
            'productId' => '3',
            'marketId' => '3',
        ],
    ];

    $command = "SELECT * FROM productImages ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
         $command .= "WHERE productId = '" . $arr[$i]['productId'] . "'" . " AND marketId = '" . $arr[$i]['marketId'] . "'";
    }

    print_r($command);

?>
```

result is 12 not sql command

Comment: String concatenation in PHP is `.` not `+`! Furthermore, the keyword `WHERE` should only appear once even if you have multiple conditions.

Comment: @Sirko for `WHERE` your right, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
 <?php
    $arr = [
        [
            'productId' => '1',
            'marketId' => '1',
        ],
        [
            'productId' => '2',
            'marketId' => '2',
        ],
        [
            'productId' => '3',
            'marketId' => '3',
        ],
    ];

    $command = "SELECT * FROM productImages WHERE ";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $command .= "(productId = '".$arr[$i]['productId']."' AND marketId = '".$arr[$i]['marketId']."')";
        if ($i < count($arr) - 1) {
            $command .= ' OR ';
        } else {
            $command .= ';';
        }
    }

    print_r($command);

?>
```

**Result:**

```
SELECT * FROM productImages WHERE (productId = '1' AND marketId = '1') OR (productId = '2' AND marketId = '2') OR (productId = '3' AND marketId = '3');
```